# Datatable does not contain a definition for AsEnumerable using LinqBridge1.1 in C#2.0

Tags: linq, asenumerable, linqbridge

i'm trying to use linq in c#2.0(linqbridge) to search for a patient name in my database,
but i'm getting the following errors:
System.Data.Datatable does not contain a definition for AsEnumerable()
System.Data.Datatable does not contain a definition for CopyToDataTable()

I added the linqBridge.dll reference to my project.
And i'm using:

using System.Linq;

```
            List<string> names = name.Split(' ').ToList();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(m_connection_string);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PATIENT", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            var query =
            from pat in ds.Tables["PATIENT"].AsEnumerable().Where(c => names.All(val => c.PAT_SEARCH_NAME.Contains(val)))
            select pat;

            DataTable table = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

What am i doing wrong?
I already read that this version of LinqBridge(1.1) does not contain this methods..
Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Have you tried adding the **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** dll to your project?

Answer (score 0):

To complete the previous answer, in case you can not add the reference to **System.Data.DataSetExtensions** using Visual Studio, I managed to do it by manually editing the library project file directly. Just insert the proper line among the existing references:

```
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Remoting" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`

In your code change to:

```
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
```